# Image path in database vs intelligent folder structure

Tags: database, path, directory

Assuming I want to safe one profile picture for each user of my system.
Is it better to save the path to this image in my database or to rely on a intelligent folder structure like

```
/images/users/user1.png
```

and access the image directly?

What if I have more then one picture per user? Would this be a good practice?

```
/images/user1/pic1.png
```

So basically my question is, why would you save the picture's path and waste space when you already know where the pictures are without any db queries?

This is just a general question apart from any technologies.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to assume that each user will have more than one picture, even if you're absolutely sure of otherwise now.. Two ways to go about it:

- Each user will have a folder for all their pictures. `/path/user1/img1.jpg` , `/path/user1/im2.gif`
- All the pictures will be in the same folder, but the `username` will be a prefix of the filename `/path/user_pics/user1_img1.jpg` ,   `/path/user_pics/user2_img3.gif`

Personally, I prefer the former.

In most cases, you won't need to store the full path of the picture in a database.. Storing the image content-type (which determines its extension) and the filename will generally be enough. That gives you more freedom as to which machine is serving the image itself.

Comment: So you mean I always have to save the image names? Even if I know there are only jpeg images with a continuous number (/user1/img1.jpg, /user1/img2.jpg, ...)? Why not just scanning the users folder (server side) for images and displaying them?

Comment: That's if you wanna keep the original name of the file, that may be important depending on the project, for distinction sake. Yes, you can just scan the folder and display the images by timestamp. But if each picture of  user1 has a caption, and you wanna display the caption along with the pic? How will you fetch the caption stored in a DB?

In any case, you don't have to store the filename itself. If each row in a table corresponds to a picture with a primary key `imageID`, a hashed string the `imageID` would be the filename in the folder. In that case, the filename would simply be redundant.